# Lewis structure with 5 atoms

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemistry

I need to obtain something similar to this:

[image]

This looks like a Lewis structure, so pairs of small x-es should rather be double dots.

My attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


$\left[\chemfig[atom sep=12pt, bond length=0pt]{\charge{0=\: ,90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{N}(-[0]H)(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)
}\right]^+$

\end{document}
```

It is tricky, as I do not know, how to omit bonds. Now they are very short but still visible.

[image]

Have we good methods to obtain a Lewis structure like this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to avoid drawing the actual bonds, you can use `bond style={draw=none}` instead of reducing the bond length:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
$\left[\chemfig[atom sep=12pt, bond style={draw=none}]{\charge{0=\: ,90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{N}(-[0]H)(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)
}\right]^+$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh! `draw=none`, not simply `none`, how I have tried.